# D3 Zoomable Pack Layout

Tags: css, d3.js

I am trying to implement the Zoomable Pack Layout code available at  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery .But when i am implementing the code my text inside the bubbles are getting overlapped .So how can i avoid this problem or sort out this problem.